# Is it possible to update third party software using Microsoft Windows Server Update Services

Tags: windows, installation, update, deployment

I am investigating Windows Server Update Service (WSUS) and the list of software to update looks pretty fixed.  Is it possible to add in third party software to the list?

If not, what are the possible options?  Microsoft SMS (think its called Systems Center now)?  Anything else?

Comment: http://www.shavlik.com/ offers their Protect software and their ties with WSUS and patch management with MS over the years would make that a good one to at least investigate.

Comment: Only Microsoft product updates can be distrubuted through WSUS.

Comment: @Ramhound it appears you are wrong - see answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can, but you need to make your own update packages, apply a certificate to them, and then import them into WSUS.  It's known as [Local Publishing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb902470%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

> The WSUS API allows you to create and publish custom updates, applications, and device drivers for your organization. The process of authoring and distributing this kind of update is called local publishing. Local publishing is best performed by organizations that have dedicated development and testing resources, since the planning, implementation, testing, and deployment of custom updates is a complex and time-consuming process.

Check out http://localupdatepubl.sourceforge.net/:

> Local Update Publisher allows system administrators to publish their own updates to Windows Server Update Services using local publishing.

Check out http://wsuspackagepublisher.codeplex.com/:

> Wsus Package Publisher allows you to publish your own updates as MSI, MSP or EXE files. Hence, you can deploy applications like Adobe Reader, Java, Flash Player or Symantec Endpoint Protection 12.1. and update them.

Couple alternatives to using WSUS:

- shavlik.com (http://www.shavlik.com/products/protect/)
- ninite.com (https://ninite.com/pro)

Comment: A recent article from from July 31, 2023 that links some precompiled, paid 3rd-party [SCUP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/configmgr/sum/tools/updates-publisher) catalogs is https://www.prajwaldesai.com/free-sccm-catalogs-for-third-party-updates/ ([archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20231116173428/https://www.prajwaldesai.com/free-sccm-catalogs-for-third-party-updates/))

Answer (score 1):

It is possible using Patch Connect Plus. Simple UI makes easy to use. It is web console based application.
https://www.manageengine.com/sccm-third-party-patch-management/